# higher order transfer function

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm trying to create this 4th order transfer function `0.5/(s^4 + 4)` in Simulink:

[image: View Image of Fourth order Transfer Function]

For some reason, I can't get a single 's^4' in the denominator of my transfer function. I'm writing it this way ['My TF'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSn3p.png), but Simulink keeps showing me this error['Error Reference'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juitP.png)

I would appreciate some help because I couldn't find any information related to my problem.

Comment: You don't have single s^4 in the image you showed that you're trying to replicate. What coefficients of numerator and denominator are you entering? (Hint: You're not entering them correctly)

Comment: Also note that `s^4 + s^3 + s^2 + s` is not *quadratic*.

Comment: Regarding the edit, you're entering s^3 as the value of coefficient. s^3 is not a coefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the function

```
0.5/(s^4 + 4)
```

Which is equal to

```
(0.5*s^0)/(1*s^4 + 0*s^3 + 0*s^2 + 0*s^1 + 4*s^0)
```

In Simulink, you parameterize the TransferFcn block by stating the numerator and denominator coefficients, in your case they can be seen to be

```
Numerator: 0.5
Denominator: 1, 0, 0, 0, 4
```

So we set up the block accordingly

[image: block]